# How to make REST api call from React app bundled into Spring boot using frontend-maven-plugin?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, maven, frontend-maven-plugin

I create a spring boot project and added a react app (created using `create react-app`) into it. I want to bundle the REST Api and the frontend in single build (fat `jar`).

Created spring boot web project, at the root added the frontend folder containing the react code. Here is the plugins inside `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>ppa-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ppa-test</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <frontend-src-dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontend-src-dir>
    <node.version>v15.7.0</node.version>
    <npm.version>7.14.0</npm.version>
    <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.7.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
          <yarnVersion>${npm.version}</yarnVersion>
          <workingDirectory>frontend</workingDirectory>
          <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install-frontend-tools</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>npm-install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>build-frontend</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>frontend/build</directory>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the [github repo link](https://github.com/Puspendert/spring-boot-react)

The project is running on `8087` and http://localhost:80807 does render the `App.js`. But inside that I made an api call to `http://localhost:8087/api/audits` which is returning `404` error. I though the Rest controller can be used like this.

What am I doing wrong here?
`@EnableWebMvc` does expose the Rest endpoint but then the `App.js` content is not served by the build.

Answer (score 0):

You were right, im sorry. I just cloned your repo and tried. It does just work. Response Code 200 with empty array.

Btw: you do not need the cors configuration. It is only needed if the frontend would be served by another webserver. But when deploying it alongside your spring in a fat-jar - its not necessary since it is not doing cors calls since its the same host.

> I just clicked in to the repo and saw your front-end code.  The path u
> are querying within axios is just
>
> ```
> axios.get("/audits")
> ```
>
> but has to be
>
> ```
> axios.get("/api/audits")
> ```
>
> since the controller is annotated with a corresponding
> `RequestMapping`.
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping("/api")
> ```

Comment: That's because, in `index.js` file I have added that into the baseURL of axios default

Comment: Yeah CORS is not needed. So did you find a solution for the problem?

Comment: As I stated above - a clean clone at that time did succeed. There was no error for me. 200 instead of 404